# Convergence of ratio of two random variables

Tags: probability-theory

If $X_n,Y_n$ are two sequences of random variables which converges to $X$ and $Y$ in probability, and $P(|Y|=0)=0$, then $\frac{X_n}{Y_n}I(Y_n \not= 0)$ converges in probability to $\frac{X}{Y}$.

Here $I$ denote the indicator function of the set. Almost similar question has been asked in the site before. I have looked at them. However, majority of them use one extra condition that $P(Y_n=0)=1$ for all $n$. But here it is given in terms of indicator functions. So, I am not getting any idea how to handle this indicator function.

Comment: I would guess that $\frac{X_n}{Y_n}I(Y_n \not= 0)$ is supposed to represent $\frac{X_n}{Y_n}$ when $Y_n \not = 0$ and represent $0$ when $Y_n=0$

Comment: Yes you are correct. Now, unlike the other cases it is not saying anything about $P(Y_n=0)=0$. So what should I do to handle this indicator function?

Comment: Your question is a consequence of the continuous mapping theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to show that $\frac{1}{Y_n}\mathbf{1}_{\{Y_n \neq 0\}} \to \frac{1}{Y}\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \neq 0\}}$ in probability. To this end, the following theorem is useful:

> [**Continuous Mapping Theorem.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ and $X$ be random variables, and $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel measurable function such that $P(g \text{ is continuous at }X) = 1$.<sup>1)</sup> Then the following implications hold.
>
> 1. If $X_n \to X$ a.s., then $g(X_n) \to g(X)$ a.s.
> 2. If $X_n \to X$ in probability, then $g(X_n) \to g(X)$ in probability.
> 3. If $X_n \to X$ in distribution, then $g(X_n) \to g(X)$ in distribution.

We refer to the link for the proof, although it will comprise a good exercise for learners. Now, by letting $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}\mathbf{1}_{\{x \neq 0 \}}$, the Continuous Mapping Theorem tells that

$$ \frac{1}{Y_n}\mathbf{1}_{\{Y_n \neq 0\}} = g(Y_n) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{\text{in prob.}} g(Y) = \frac{1}{Y} \mathbf{1}_{\{Y \neq 0 \}}. $$

---

1) For *any* function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, the set $\mathcal{C}$ of all continuity point of $g$ is a $G_{\delta}$-set, hence Borel measurable. Therefore, $X^{-1}(\mathcal{C})$ is indeed an event for each random variable $X$.